# Is it "safe" to use comments to explain the functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, security

Is it "safe" to put comments explaining the functions of the script in Javascript ? (Visible inside the public script)

Given that every users can read and modify the "Javascript", does the fact of using comments directly in the script could be dangerous ?

Because if I was a "hacker" and wanted to find an exploit, I think comments in the script explaining all the functions would make my life easier...

Comment: Aren't you going to just minify that away anyway?

Comment: Hackers are very experienced programmers. They can look at your code and figure out what it does very easily.

Comment: Security through obscurity is the weakest form of security.

Comment: Downvote ? why, my question is not clear ? I always wanted to know if I should put comment or not. And if yes, does it "may" impact the security ?

Comment: It may impact security if your security is really bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Skilled hackers don't need any comments.

You can never rely on anything on the client for security; all security boundaries must be verified on the server.

Comment: this is true, but it sends the wrong impression. basic validation should also be performed client side, then checked again server side. i know it really doesn't matter since a hacker never uses your web interface anyway, but its still good practice for everyone else who visits your website.

Comment: @r3wt: yes, but client-side validation is a courtesy to the user (to prevent wasted time, page-submissions and problems with invalid data): it's definitely *not* secure, therefore can't be considered 'security.'

Comment: @DavidThomas you're right, that was basically my entire point.

Comment: @r3wt: But this answer is about security, not user experience.

Comment: @FelixKling all i'm saying is, it doesn't hurt to throw in that little bit of extra clarification.

Comment: @r3wt: Sure, but the statement "sending the wrong impression" is out of place. It sends the correct impression: don't rely on security stuff on the client side.

Comment: @FelixKling Good day.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, no ...it's not safe. It's really up to you and your specific situation. I bundle and minify personally, which removes those comments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on really what your program or script is designed to do. If it is a script that deals with secure information or data storage then the code itself should not be able to be modified by every user. Users designed to use the program should have access only to running the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can add whatever comments you want in your javascript code, however make sure that you minify the files (that removes the comments) and make non minified files not accessible

Answer (score 1):

There is no expectation of your source code being secure client side. Anyone can view your html, css, and javascript files if they wanted to.
Instead, focus on making sure that data flow is secure between client and server. For example, use https when dealing with passwords, credit card numbers, and other sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

You can add as much comments as you want. Adding a comment behind a function is not going to cause any trouble and will give you a better view on how you script works. I personally add comments to my scripts ofter, because then I can tell easier what the function does.